# OpenLayers3: Find the parameters from a WMTS service

Tags: openlayers, wmts

I'm trying to add a WMTS layer in an OpenLayers3 project. I'm able to add this layer in QGIS. Here is the service address: http://www.ngi.be/cartoweb/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml.

In OpenLayers3, I tried several combination of parameters. The last in date is this one:

```
var ignLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
     url: 'http://www.ngi.be/cartoweb/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml',
     params: {
          'Layer': 'CartoWeb-Topo',
          'Tileset': '3857',
          },
     format: 'image/png'
     })
 });
```

Do you think am I missing a mandatory parameter? Or maybe the source TileWMS is not the one to use?

Here are the results of GET queries:
[image: WMST Get Requests Results]

Comment: Do you get any error message? Does the service respond anything?

Comment: Yes. The service respond a 200 HTTP Status Code. But the results are empty images. I added an image of the GET queries results.

Comment: I assume, that you use the wrong URL. The one you show is probably only the capabilities document. If you have a look in there for ResourceURL, it tells you, which path to use: `ResourceURL resourceType="tile" template="http://www.ngi.be/cartoweb/1.0.0/topo/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}.png" format="image/png"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to your comments, I'm now able to add the belgian NGI WMTS to an OpenLayers3 project. Here is how:

```
var belgiumExtent = [280000, 6360000, 710000, 6710000];

var ignMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: belgiumExtent,
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'http://www.ngi.be/cartoweb/1.0.0/' +
           'topo/default/3857/{z}/{y}/{x}.png'
    })
 });
```

As you notice, I'm using the XYZ format. I didn't figure out how to use the WMTS format. Maybe here is a way to do it: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/examples/wmts-ign.html?q=wmts.

Moreover, I'm using the Google Mercator projection (EPSG:3857). If you need it, the belgian Lambert 2008 projection is also available (EPSG:3812).